# hasClass with anonymous function not working

Tags: jquery

why this wouldn't work?

```
$(".li").hasClass('active', function(){
            alert('work!');
    });
```

I want select the active li and do something on it..

Comment: what are you trying to do here

Comment: It doesn't work because it's not supposed to work. Where do you see in the documentation of `hashClass` that it takes a function argument? http://api.jquery.com/hasClass/

Comment: Shouldn't that be `$("li")`?

Answer (score 3):

Change to this :

```
if($('.li').hasClass('active')){
   alert('work!');
}
```

**Update**

I think you need create a `function` to realize this :

```
function effect(element){
   if($(element).hasClass('active')){
     alert('work!');
   }
}
```

Call it :

```
effect('.li');
effect('.lu');
effect('.le');
.....
```

Comment: it worked! thx, but im working on dynamic elements. what if I want it to be real-time up-datable? how to bind it with on() ?

Comment: what do you mean real-time up-datable? the element or if the true statement?

Comment: the above code work once, after I have let say new li elements, it won't execute anymore..

Answer (score 0):

Or if you want to store a function by it's name to use on any element later on down the road, you can do this:

```
$.fn.extend({
    myFunction : function(){ alert('work'); }
});

$('.active').myFunction();
```

This performs the function only on the `class="active"` element(s), but you can use the same function on any other elements as well.

Comment: will this work if newly element added and tht element has a class active?

Comment: Well, it depends on where the function call is located.  You can call it after adding the element sure...

Answer (score 0):

"I want select the active li and do something on it.."

So what you really want is bind an event on the active `li` so this should work as expected.

```
$(".li.active").on('click', function() { // Supossing li is a class not an element.
            alert('work!');
    });
```

hasClass is only an function wich will return true or false if the element sended has the class.